# Чи є питомою форма "приїжджати"?

Tags: дієслова, чергування

В літературі доволі часто можна зустріти дієслово в обох граматичних видах (аспектах):

- *приїздити* — доконаному, коли йдеться про дію, яка повністю відбулася;
- *приїжджати* — недоконаному, коли йдеться про відбування процесу у часі;

Наприклад, Микола Мозговий – «Край» ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEzhAUihaFU)):

> ***Приїжджайте*** в Прикарпаття,
>   Приїжджайте, люди добрі,
>   Завше будуть раді вам…

СУМ вважає основною формою [*приїжджати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjizhdzhaty), у той час як [*приїздити*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjizdyty) — «див. приїжджати».

Словник Грінченка, навпаки, вважає основною формою [*приїздити*](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8), *приї**ж**джати* відсутнє, [*приї**з**джати*](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) — «= Приїздити».

З морфологічної точки зору, заперечень нема: корінь `-їзд-` + суфікс `-ж-` і закінчення `-ати`.

З субʼєктивно-естетичної точки зору, обидва варіанти `-ждж-` і `-здж-` мені не подобаються. У повсякденному спілкуванні я намагаюся уникати цієї форми. Але не упевнений, чи мої побоювання мають підґрунтя.

Запитання: чи є питомим варіант *«приї**ж**джати»* або *«приї**з**джати»*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Українська мова](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=tQoLAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B6%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> … коли поліські писарі 16–17 ст., відображаючи форми дієслова *їздити* та *дощ*, відтворювали рефлекс *zdj найрізноманітнішими (іноді навіть важко уявлювати, не те, що вимовлюваними: *жд, жьдж, ждж, ждз, (з)дж, жч, жьч, ждч, жьдч, жджч*) поєднаннями графем, то чому …

[Причинки до історії української мови](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=XdQACgAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&ots=322B_xZN0_&sig=I1A3CY88CFhdmxcnGRo-x6KQxXA#v=onepage&q&f=false) ([Міхаель Мозер](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80))

> На увагу заслуговує псковський, смоленський і полоцький рефлекс сполук ****stj, skj, sk’, zdj, zgj, zg’***, а саме [š’k’], ＞ J — та він, мабуть походить від ***šč***, про що свідчить злиття ***sk’*** і ***skj***.

[Вибрані праці](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=pqwjAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B6) ([Павло Житецький](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%93%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87))

> … але в українській і білоруській мові є ще *дж* з того ж *дj* = церковнослов. *жд*, а також *ждж* із *здj*, напр.: *приижджати*, білор. *прийажджаць*.  Залишаючи осторонь питання про відношення *дж* до *жд*, зауважимо, що *жд*, *ждж* є одна із давніх прикмет українського консонантизму.

[Наукові записки](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=eLgWAQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B6)

> … мовах винико внаслідок перехідного помʼякшення і асимілятивно-дисимілятивних процесів, де в давніх сполученнях **д** + *j*, **т** + *j*, **зд** + *j*, **ст** + *j* палатальний за своєю природою *j* уподібнився після дзвінких до **ж**, а після глухих — до **ш**.
>
> Таким чином, в українській мові ці фонетичні форми виникли в такий спосіб:
>
> - **д** + *j* ＞ **дж**;
> - **т** + *j* ＞ **тш**-**ч**;
> - **зд** + *j* ＞ **здж** ＞ **ждж**

---

### Коротко

- Сполуки **здж** і **ждж** є питомими. Про всяк, **дж** є *одним* звуком, глухим відповідником є **ч**. Якби записувати за македонською, було би умовне **жџ**.
- Палаталізацією до **зд** є **ждж** або старіше **здж**, тобто **-ж-** не є зовсім суфіксом.
- Різниця лише ві віці, від найстарішого:  **здj** ＞ **здж** ＞ **ждж**. Тобто останній є найсучаснішим способом. Про всяк, говірки можуть мати інші варіяції розвитку, наприклад **зд<sup>j</sup>**, тобто умовне [*приїздю*](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=XW9pAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8E%22).

Аби простіше сприймати ці сполуки, наведу до прикладу глуху і звичну пару:

> *про**ст**ити* — *про**щ**ати*, тобто *про**шч**ати*

Тут **-ати** палаталізують і вказують на наворотність чи недоконаність.

---

Іще приклад, якщо не дуже охочі до **дз**, **дж**: раніше (до правопису 1960) деякі дієслова (переважно із закінченням **-істи**) мали наказовий спосіб із закінченням **дж**: *розповідж, їдж, відповідж* тощо.